Horizontal forces of a wheel that is rolling and slipping while subjected to a coupled moment?
I am trying to understand what's going on with this problem:



I summed the forces in the $x$-axis, which is horizontal, and I thought the moment would create a force opposing the friction force. However, the given solution only included the friction force:
$$F_\text{friction} = ma.$$
My equation was:
$$F_\text{friction} - M/r = ma.$$
Why is the force caused by the moment excluded? Is it because there is slipping? If that was the case, would you include the force caused by a moment in a non-slipping scenario?

Voting to reopen. OP is not asking how to do the problem.

I'm not 100% familiar with the engineering terminology you're using, but a quick google reveals that

A special case of moments is a couple. A couple consists of two parallel forces that are equal in magnitude, opposite in sense and do not share a line of action. It does not produce any translation, only rotation. The resultant force of a couple is zero. BUT, the resultant of a couple is not zero; it is a pure moment.

So since the external agency is exerting a "couple moment" it does not apply a net force, only a torque (moment) about the center.

Ah thanks! I don't know why I was overlooking that...

Actually...apparently it's a little more involved than that. It turns out problems with moments that are not labeled "coupled" and the M/r force is still not included. I think I know why though.

Also, the "coupled" forces aren't specified. and the distance between them is unknown. So we can't know that the M/r would be one of the coupled forces.

The midpoint between the coupled forces me not be at G either.

I think the issue was that I was considering the force M/r as the resultant force. If I do that though, then I cannot simultaneously consider F(friction) because that friction force only exists as a result of the moment in this problem. In other words, the friction force is the resultant force of the moment. Everything the moment does (besides turning the wheel) goes into the friction force and so the friction force is the total force in the x axis.
